# How to get values of different columns by different roles on other columns in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table that include few row from each clientID. each row came from different company and different validation date.

for example (you can find it at [this link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f283488889bf42f4434a024ceece5ca4) too):

```
ID    |COMPANY|GENDER|AGE|IS_SMOKER|VALIDATION_DATE |ZIP    |ZIP_VALIDATION_DATE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1111  | 1     | m    |44 |  1      |    02-MAR-03   |12345  |02-MAR-03
1111  | 3     | m    |43 |  NULL   |    03-FEB-10   |11111  |03-FEB-00
2222  | 1     | f    |20 |  0      |    04-APR-00   |22344  |04-APR-00
2222  | 3     | f    |50 |  0      |    05-MAY-82   |22344  |05-MAY-82
3333  | 1     | f    |34 |  0      |    05-MAY-01   |33333  |01-MAY-00
3333  | 7     | f    |34 |  1      |    05-MAY-00   |22222  |05-MAY-00
4444  | 3     | m    |95 |  NULL   |    06-JUN-03   |12345  |02-MAR-03
```

I want to get one line per ID but with different role for each data:

- zip code but the max of ZIP_VALIDATION_DATE
- smoker - if it is smoker (1) in any company get 1 else if it have 0 get 0 if null get null
- other data - by max VALIDATION_DATE

The result I want is:

```
ID    |GENDER|AGE|IS_SMOKER|ZIP 
---------------------------------
1111  | m    |43 |  1      |12345
2222  | f    |20 |  0      |22344
3333  | f    |34 |  1      |22222
4444  | m    |95 |  NULL   |12345
```

NOTE:

- the validation_date is good for several columns when ZIP_VALIDATION_DATE is valide only for one columns.
- I have few more columns with different role (like the smoker) and another specific validation date but. I didn't add it to the example but I suppose it will be the same implementation.

I try to find the most efficient way to do this, but I don't have limitation to use OVER PARTITION, WITH, sub_query or something else.

Comment: Nothing in your data is called "client".

Comment: I hope your system complies with all relevant laws regarding [personal data protection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Data_Protection_Regulation).

Comment: @GordonLinoff Client is defined but ID, I edit my question.
WilliamRobertson yes, I am working by all the relevant regulations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I follow the logic correctly, you can use Oracle's `keep` functionality with aggregation:

```
select id, 
       max(gender) keep (dense_rank first order by validation_date desc) as gender,
       max(is_smoker),
       max(age) keep (dense_rank first order by validation_date desc) as age,
       max(zip) keep (dense_rank first order by ZIP_VALIDATION_DATE desc) as zip
from my_table t
group by id
order by id;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=3f22965f282a5b52014e16d189d1d524) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: It's work. this is want I am doing. but do It have better solution if we have 10 columns that I need to check validation days? 
Or what is more efficient. to do 10 keep statement or to use join of sub query  by different partitions?

Comment: @yonabendelac . . . I have found that aggregation with `keep` is surprisingly good in performance in Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

Please use below query,

```
select id, gender, age, is_smoker, zip from
(select id, gender, age, is_smoker, zip, 
row_number() over(partition by id order by validation_date desc) as rnk
from table_name) qry where rnk = 1;
```

below is the demo,

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c834e8e07d58f714955eccb9704fc34b

Comment: This is right when I want to get all row by one condition (by validation_date) but I want part of a row by validation date and part by zip_validation_date and more data by different roles